# VSCode + Docker setup problems on Windows

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I'm trying to setup the local enviroment by the VSCode + Docker way, because i find it easier for a newbie like me.
I open the cloned repository on VSCode but when y click on the button to reopen it in the Docker container y get this error:

[image]

I think that the problem is in the devcontainer.json file, exactly for this setting:

```
"settings": {
    // Note: don't change from bash so it runs .bashrc
    "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
},
```

I think this is an incorrect property because i'm on Windows, not Linux, but i have no idea of what i should put in there to replace it.

I wil appreciate any help because i'm a total newbie to all this environment.

Comment: I think it will help if you actually describe how you are running the installation. Question: Have you installed the Remote Development extension pack for VS?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Look at line 11 of devcontainer.json:

```
"source=${localEnv:HOME}/.cabal/packages,target=/home/plutus/.cabal/packages,type=bind,consistency=cached"
```

Believe it or not, I solved this error by going into my environment variables and creating a variable name HOME that points to my user directory C:\Users\$username.

This is also mentioned in an answer to another Windows-specific issue: [Problem starting a plutus devcontainer in windows](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/382/problem-starting-a-plutus-devcontainer-in-windows) where the solution is to change the variable from HOME to USERPROFILE.